# Title overlaps the main application body in Android app

Tags: android, xml

I am making an Android application (API 19) for a school project and the top of the body of the app is obstructed by the title. In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lniVX.png) you can see what I am trying to do. Eliminating the title altogether can also be desirable (this: ***android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"*** seems not to have any effect).

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#707070"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

     <!-- this is here only to display the first line correctly (zero container)-->
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >

          <!--some functionality was necessary to avoid warnings-->
         <TextClock
             android:id="@+id/textClock1"
             android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/textClock" />  
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this is the first container -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >

        <!-- this is the heart rate interval progress bar -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.06" />

        <!-- this is a blue heart icon -->
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/heartIcon"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/button_heart_blue" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- code omitted -->


</LinearLayout>
```

I am not happy with the "solution" I came up with. Is there a more clean way to code this functionality?

I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: have u checked my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**do not insert that attribute in ur xml layout add this in ur project's `manifest` file**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

in `application tag` like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
        android:largeHeap="true">
```

that makes ur application full screen

or in `activity` tag which activity u want to show full screen like this

```
<activity android:name="your_activity_name"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

or u can do it in java code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//for removing tittle bar
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//for removing notification bar if u want to remove it
```

Comment: I show u 3 different way how to hide tittle bar u can use any one of them cheers :) if u want to hide tittle bar through out ur app then go for the first solution

Comment: It works. I put the code in the `activity` tag of the AndroidManifest.xml file like you suggested. The title is now gone. But this solution will remove the title from all screens of the application, not only the one that the specific .xml was meant to configure. Would there be some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title bar in your activity's code calling:

```
activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As advised by kaushik, in order to completely remove the title from all application windows, we have to edit the AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <!-- android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" -->
            <!-- this was replaced in order to get rid of the title -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```